# argparse module How to add option without any argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I have created a script using `argparse`.

The script needs to take a configuration file name as an option, and user can specify whether they need to proceed totally the script or only simulate it.

The args to be passed: `./script -f config_file -s` or `./script -f config_file`.

It's ok for the -f config_file part, but It keeps asking me for arguments for the -s which is optionnal and should not be followed by any.

I have tried this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file')
#parser.add_argument('-s', '--simulate', nargs = '0')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.file:
    config_file = args.file
if args.set_in_prod:
        simulate = True
else:
    pass
```

With the following errors:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/argparse.py", line 2169, in _get_nargs_pattern
nargs_pattern = '(-*%s-*)' % '-*'.join('A' * nargs)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

And same errror with `''` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

As [@Felix Kling suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262702/argparse-module-how-to-add-option-without-any-argument/5262769#5262769), to create an option that needs no value, use `action='store_true'`, `'store_false'` or `'store_const'`. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action).

```
>>> from argparse import ArgumentParser
>>> p = ArgumentParser()
>>> _ = p.add_argument('-f', '--foo', action='store_true')
>>> args = p.parse_args()
>>> args.foo
False
>>> args = p.parse_args(['-f'])
>>> args.foo
True
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-s` instead of `-f` ?  AFAIK the -f option should have a filename as an option and the -s option trigger the dry-run behaviour. Or am I understanding it the wrong way?

Comment: `-f` is short for `--foo` as in [`foobar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) -- just a placeholder/dummy name -- no semantics.

Answer (score 138):

To create an option that needs no value, set the [`action` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) of it to `'store_const'`, `'store_true'` or `'store_false'`.

Example:

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--simulate', action='store_true')
```

Comment: Hello;Thanks for your answer.
I have tried as explained in the doc:

>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', '-f', action='store_true')

_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--foo', '-f'], dest='foo', 

nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, 

help=None, metavar=None)

>>> parser.parse_args()

Namespace(foo=False)

>>> print args.foo

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'foo'

>>>`

This does not seem to work;
I Don't know how to retrieve the value after assignation.
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @philippe: you've forgot to bind `parser.parse_args()` returned value to `args` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262702/argparse-module-how-to-add-option-without-any-argument/5271692#5271692

Comment: @philippe: `args = parser.parse_args()` as you already have in your code. You just have to replace the commented line and then you can access the value with `args.simulate`.