# How to import the module which using argparse

Tags: python

I got the module call foo.py, use argparse to handle variables, requires some variables, -a and a element

```
python foo.py -a element
```

This works well, now I get a list of elements, I try to use foo.py to run all of them.So I create a script like this:

```
import foo
for i in range(len(element)):
# how to run foo and pass -a here?
```

another option will be use execfile()

```
execfile("foo.py") #should I set the -a as some global variable here?
```

I follow here [argparse module How to add option without any argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262702/argparse-module-how-to-add-option-without-any-argument), I don't quite understand how to do this.

### EDIT

Follow [importing a python script from another script and running it with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440441/importing-a-python-script-from-another-script-and-running-it-with-arguments), Now I can run the script well, But any better solution than add a list to sys.args? Or I have to add the element first, after the main() finish, than delete it from sys.args and over and over again.

Comment: Is this not what you want? `p.add_argument('-f', '--foo', action='store_true')` I'm confused on what you're asking.  If you wan like a boolean thing then `store_true` is the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [importing a python script from another script and running it with arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440441/importing-a-python-script-from-another-script-and-running-it-with-arguments)

Comment: @karin - interesting link but will not work for scripts that use a `if __name__ == "__main__":` conditional because the imported module will have a different name.

Comment: Ideally a script intended to be used as a script and a module has some sort of _main_ function that takes an argv-like parameter list. If so, just call that function with the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Karin,This works great.

```
import sys
sys.argv += ['-a','-H MYHOSTNAME' .... other options]
from pyrseas import dbtoyaml
dbtoyaml.main()
```

And this also work.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'foo.py',  '-a', 'bala'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```